# What’s the performance difference between moving(sum, X, 10) and msum(X, 10) and what causes the difference?

Tags: database-performance, dolphindb

For a vector of length 1 million, what’s the performance difference between moving(sum, X, 10) and msum(X, 10) and what causes the difference?

Answer (score 0):

The calculation speed of function [msum](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/m/msum.html) will be 50 to 200 times higher than the [moving](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/Functionalprogramming/TemplateFunctions/moving.html) function. It may vary depending on the data volume. The reasons are as follows:

1. The functions adopt different methods to process data: msum puts data into memory at one time, no need to allocate memory separately for each calculation; while moving generates a sub-object and reallocates memory to the sub-object for each calculation, and the memory is reclaimed after the calculation completes.
2. The function msum implements incremental computation where each calculation adds the previous result to the adjacent value and subtract the last value of the previous calculation, while moving adds up all the data in the window for each calculation.